# rotating multiple divs around a central point via css3 transforms

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I am trying to rotate some elements around a central point with css3 but with not much luck.
Basically I have a function that places n elements (divs) around a circumference and what I'd like to do is move each element to the next position with css3.

Note: rotatorElements is an array with all the elements.

```
for (var i=0; i<rotatorElements['obj'].length; i++){

   $thisobj = $('.slice-'+rotatorElements['obj'][i]);

  startDegrees = rotatorElements['angle_s'][i];
  endDegrees = rotatorElements['angle_e'][i];


  newDiv = $thisobj.get(0);
  goX = (options.circle.x-newDiv.offsetLeft)+'px';
  goY = (options.circle.y-newDiv.offsetTop)+'px';
  $thisobj.css("transform-origin", goX+" "+goY);

  newDiv.style.webkitTransition = newDiv.style.MozTransition =
  newDiv.style.OTransition = newDiv.style.transition =
  'all 1s ease-in-out';

  newDiv.style.webkitTransform = newDiv.style.MozTransform =
  newDiv.style.OTransform = newDiv.style.transform =
  'rotate('+sliceDegrees+'deg)';
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please put the actual code for rotatorElements, d

Comment: it looks like you're using jQuery for the transform-origin, so why aren't you using it for the transition or the rotate?